# modify int to float (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to change datatype from INT to FLOAT in MySQL like this:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY rate float(5) NOT NULL
```

But current data is droped. Is there any way to convent\save data from INT to FLOAT with SQL?

Comment: One approach would be to 1. Add a new column with the new type. 2. Copy over all of the data from the old column to the new column. 3. Remove the old column.

Comment: Could you add a sample to SQLfiddle where current data is actually dropped? It shouldn't be, and [I can't make it happen](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeade/1).

Comment: Joachim Isaksson, MySQL 5.5.30, InnoDB. True story. Sorry, I can't provide a sample.

Comment: @Aiias If you provide an absolutely perfect solution in the comment field instead of as an answer, it is your own fault that you don't get any points for it...

Comment: I bet you want DECIMAL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE rate intrate INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD rate float(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 100;
UPDATE `user` SET rate=intrate;
ALTER TABLE `user` DROP intrate;
```

Answer (score 20):

I have just tried

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY rate float(5) NOT NULL
```

with mysql 5.6.26 and it worked without dropping the value.

Comment: True story. Roger that!