# Sql Cast conversion from int to float

Tags: sql

```
declare @alpha float
declare @tmp int

set @tmp = 6
set @alpha = 1/@tmp

select @alpha 
        >> Here @alpha is echoed as 0

declare @tmp1 float

set @tmp1 = 6
set @alpha = 1/@tmp1

select @alpha 
      >> Here @alpha is echoed as 0.1666666
```

I would be fine with it if it at least threw up a warning but the compiler does not throw any warning either. Or is there a compiler setting for such kinds of cast operations to automatically convert it into the desired cast.

I mean it is not hard to convert an int to float and vice versa is my rationale. The other logical question is if it does not allow date variable to a `varchar` variable, why should it allow `int` to `float` and end up giving the undesired result.

Comment: because i have set @alpha variable as a float

Comment: The compiler can't give you a warning because it can't tell when you want integer math or floating point math.

Comment: ya i missed the part of posting declare @alpha float.. so shudnt the compiler know it has got more space to fit in the variable and deduce that it is floating point math.. im ok with it doing integer math but then it does not alert me and i find that somewhat odd

Comment: Select 1/6 yields 0.  Select 1.0 / 6 yields 0.166666. Select 1/6.0 yields 0.16666. Select 1.0/6.0 yields 0.16666. So I normally make sure my numeric literals are floats if I want to assign the result of an operation to a variable declared as float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [modify int to float (mysql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859487/modify-int-to-float-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx) will be useful, maybe you should use cast or convert functions after the divison or use a float value in some of its operators (dependending of what you need to do), because:

**Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence. For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).
If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated**

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5543) some examples.